# How to roll backup outlook 2010

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, windows-server-2003

I want roll back my outlook 2010 from my current version that is 14.0.6131.5000 to 14.0.6120.5000. How should I do ?
I have a lot of KB upgrades installed but I dont know which one to uninstall.

Comment: You can sort the list of updates by name and check their details, or go to `Windows Update\View update history\Installed Updates` which shows Office-related updates separately (which might make it easy to narrow down which update it was).

Comment: @Karan   it's Win 2k3